# Is there any way to read and write orc files without hadoop in Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, orc

My service should get files with different formats and getting informations from them. One of that format is `orc`. Is there a way to read it from `RAM` (as byte array) without `hadoop` and other additional systems? Can't find any way in google. :(